# How to distribute application in cakephp?Page not found

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have a problem to distribute my application in cakephp. The point is that I have my application in the folder **/example** on my server A. if I copy the folder /example on another server B, with all configured in the same way that server A, then The server B displays page not found. when I try to access the application.

The application does not work until I change:

`Configure :: write ('debug', 0);`  to  `Configure :: write ('debug', 2);`

At this time the application runs without showing any problem.

What can be the problem?

Comment: You know what the debug level does? Look it up in the book. You should not run your site in debug 2 as it exposes internals of your site to the public and makes it easier to attack it. What can be the problem: Did you check your log files in /tmp/logs? If not show them here.

Comment: Turn debug off again and see if it works. It may have just needed the cache clearing,

Comment: what I want to do is to distribute the application with debug mode = 0 by default. But the problem is that if I copy the application in debug mode = 0, this does not work until I change it to debug = 2. After that I can put it back into debug mode = 0 and the application works normally.

Comment: I found the solution!! the problem was in the files of the folder /tmp. I delete all files and the application works fine without having to change anything. Thank you!